# Инстанцирование шаблона non-const значением

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть ли в крестах возможность инстанцировать шаблон типа

```
template<size_t dim>
class foo { }
```

неконстантным значением?
Например так:

```
size_t order = 1;
order = get_order();
foo<order> instance;
```

Если да - есть ли возможность возвращать значение на шаблонный объект с неизвестным параметром шаблона:

```
foo get_foo()
{
  size_t order = 1;
  order = get_order();
  foo<order> instance;

  return instance;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет. Тип должен быть вычисляем в момент времени компиляции. Причём не обязательно при инициализации должно использоваться `const` значение, но обязательно `constexpr`. Про `constexpr` нормально написано на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/228181/).

Comment: Неужели нет никакого способа? Пусть даже костыльного.

Comment: никакого нет. С++ -- статически типизированный язык. ([разница статической и динамической типизации](https://habrahabr.ru/post/308484/) ). В частности это значит, что вся работа с типами происходит на этапе компиляции. То есть  уже компилятор про каждую переменную должен знать, какого она типа.

Comment: @Gordory, а вам обязательно нужен шаблон? Может вас устроит класс с параметром в конструкторе и динамически выделяемой памятью?

Comment: @ГерманБорисов пришлось так и сделать, но для этого потребовалось создавать класс аналогичный шаблонному, что не очень красиво вышло.

Comment: @Gordory скорее всего шаблонный класс Вам не нужен вовсе.

Comment: @alexolut хм, и с чего вы так предположили? У меня просто несколько параметров шаблона, от одного пришлось избавиться в пользу параметра конструктора.

Comment: @Gordory я руководствовался исключительно предоставленной в вопросе информацией. Для реализации описанной идеи шаблон не нужен.